# AMD ATI video driver causing BSOD after installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, ati-mobility-radeon

I recently re-installed **Windows 7 Home Premium on my Dell Inspiron N5010** laptop. Initially without the video driver, everything was fine except that the screen icons and applications windows were of disproportionate size.

But, then I decided to install video driver. The Dell Website suggested two video drivers for my laptop when I gave them my Service Tag. One was **Intel(R) HD graphics** and the other one is **ATI AMD Mobility Radeon 5470**. When I tried installing the Intel driver, it said that "**Your computer doesn't support the minimum requirements**". So, I turned to ATI driver and installed it. But after I installed the driver and rebooted my laptop, I got a **BSOD**. BSOD occured at the time when the login screen is supposed to appear. The BSOD code is **0X0116** and there is a reference to **atikmpag.sys** in the BSOD.

Then, I rebooted in **Safe Mode** and **unistalled** the driver. After this, when I logged in again, there was no BSOD.

Can anybody help me in identifying the problem.

Comment: Maybe the Intel driver was the right one and you could not install it, because the other hardware was not recognized. Try to start in safe mode, go to you Hardware Manager, look for Hardware ID and google it. You will find out, what driver you need.

Comment: @Watsche....thanks for the response...The device is AMD Mobility Radeon 5470....

Comment: I would say: Bios update.

Comment: My Bios is updated to A15 version which according to Dell Website is the latest

Comment: @Watsche...is it possible that my graphic card has become faulty?

Comment: It is very implausible, that your card got this faulty exactly at the time, where you reinstalled your windows. I will think about it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following source, problems with the ATI Driver are the likely culprit, fortunately the solution is outline below:

[Source Forum](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1656824/atikmdag-sys-error-bsod-startup.html)

Step 1: Download and install the latest ATI graphic driver. AND DON'T TURN OFF OR RESTART YOUR COMPUTER AFTER INSTALLATION.

Step 2: Then go to *C:\Windows\System32\Drivers* and rename *atikmdag.sys* to *atikmdag.sys.old*.

Step 3: Go to ATI directory (usually in *C:\ATI*) and find the file *atikmdag.sy_*.

Step 4: Copy the file to your Desktop directory.

Step 5: Open *cmd.exe* by going to <kbd>Start</kbd> -> type *cmd* in the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Step 6: Change the directory to Desktop by typing `chdir Desktop`.

Step 7: Then, type `EXPAND.EXE atikmdag.sy_ atikmdag.sys`. Or,

`expand -r atikmdag.sy_ atikmdag.sys`

Step 8: When the expansion is complete, copy the new *atikmdag.sys* from your Desktop to *C:\Windows\System32\Drivers*

Step 9: Restart your computer and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear it! No problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here. Solution was much simpler. Before installing/reinstalling windows, format both the target partition and the 100 MB partition created by previous installation. Worked for me.